# Impossible to start phpmyadmin

Tags: php, web, phpmyadmin, installation, localhost

i have a problem, i cant use phpmyadmin in my browser, i try :

```
http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/ 
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/
```

Installed packages:

```
php5 ,
php5-mysql,
php5-cli ,
php5-pear,
phpdoc,
php5-xdebug ,
ant ,
mysql-client ,
mysql-server
```

phpmyadmin is not found in my Dash Home .

tanks

Comment: how you installed your web server?

Comment: phpmyadmin isn't delivered with PHP. you need to install it separately

Comment: i use :

sudo apt-get install php5
. . .
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin

Comment: did you follow all this? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/phpMyAdmin if so it should work

Comment: try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin` . Check `apache` in the web server section

Comment: i try sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin :
writing config to /etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf
Replacing config file /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php with new version
granting access to database phpmyadmin for phpmyadmin@localhost: already exists.
creating database phpmyadmin: already exists.
populating database via sql...  done.
dbconfig-common: flushing administrative password

apache server is ok, i can see my website in http://127.0.0.1/index

Comment: problem resolved :
first : 'sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf'
then : 'sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload'
thanks all !

Comment: which os are you using?